# How to pronounce Fritz Leiber's name?

Tags: pronunciation, fritz-leiber

I'm looking for a definitive answer on how to pronounce Fritz Leiber's last name. I guess audio of him or a close family member would be ideal, or maybe he addressed it somewhere in writing.

I and people I know have always pronounced it LEE-ber (IPA /'libər/), but tonight I heard [a podcast episode](https://www.claytemplemedia.com/eldersign) use LIE-ber (/'laibər/). [Pronouncekiwi](https://www.pronouncekiwi.com/Fritz%20Reuter%20Leiber,%20Jr.) gives

|  | /i/ | /ai/ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Australian English | 3 | 0 |
| UK English | 4 | 0 |
| Indian English | 1 | 0 |
| US English | 2 | 8 |
| Welsh English | 1 | 0 |

No consensus!

Comment: It's pronounced Throat-Warbler Mangrove.

Comment: @Lexible, it's pronounced 'Bouquet'

Comment: I'm in the US and would've guessed LAY-ber as per the English (Australia) pronunciations on that wiki

Comment: Thanks for asking this! Likewise a few weeks back on [my D&D talk show](https://youtu.be/PCtXdgkfEvg?t=1698), I was saying "LEE-ber", and a minute later our guest Mike Curtis (who found a previously unknown manuscript by F.L.) said "LYE-ber", which threw me off. So I was wondering exactly this! Wish I could bounty a question.

Comment: Setting aside possible variations in how any individual (e.g. Fritz Leiber) may pronounce their own name... "Leiber" is originally a German surname, and thus follows [German phonetic rules](http://joycep.myweb.port.ac.uk/pronounce/vowelei.html); the diphthong spelled "ei" is pronounced as /aɪ/ (i.e. like "lie"; [an example](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/File:De-Leiber.ogg)).

Comment: @V2Blast As has been pointed out several times on this page, the _origin_ of a name and the _current_ pronunciation are very different things. Absent other evidence, both standard German pronunciation and standard American English pronunciation would be reasonable guesses for a third-generation German-American.

Comment: How on earth is this question on-topic?

Comment: It's always the name of the second letter. "ie" is pronounced like "e", "ei" is pronounced like "i".

Comment: If asking for the pronunciation of a fictional name is on-topic, why shouldn't we be allowed to ask for the pronunciation of a science fiction author's name?

Comment: @InvisibleTrihedron The pronunciation of a fictional character's name is on-topic because that relates to the canon of whatever universe that character is in. A question about an author's name has nothing to do with any canon. Would a question about a scifi author's birthday be on-topic?

Comment: @pacoverflow I see your point, but knowing the pronunciation makes it easier to discuss a science fiction author's work. Authors' birthdays are, in fact, listed on the ISFDB, though requesting the birthday of a living person may be intrusive. Authors usually prefer to have people pronounce their names correctly.

Comment: It's interesting that none of the en-gb examples are pronounced as if he was German.  I'm British and that would be my assumption (but then I speak a little German).

Comment: @IMSoP: That's why I left it as a comment and not an answer. :)

Answer (score 100, accepted):

In this videotaped interview the interviewer initially mispronounces Fritz Leiber's name as LEE-ber (rhyming with Bieber) but Leiber corrects him,

> "*My name is LYE-ber*" [rhyming with cyber].

Comment: Perfect, thank you! (And also glad to hear that I'm right about /'fæfərd/.)

Comment: Fritz Leiber is German. I before e is “—ee—.”  E before i is “—eye—.”

Comment: @SillybutTrue is that good guidance, or a grammatic rule? (honestly don't know)

Comment: @CGCampbell Actually the SF writer Fritz Leiber was not a German. He was an American, born in Chicago. He had a German grandfather. It is true that in German ei is always pronounced as in the English word height. So the German pronunciation of Leiber rhymes with the English word cyber. It's anybody's guess how an American Leiber would pronounce the name. E.g., Sissy Spacek does not pronounce her surname in the Czech fashion, nor Matt Nagy his in the Hungarian. It so happens that Fritz Leiber used the German pronunciation of his last name.

Comment: @CGCampbell In German language, it is a grammatical rule (and unlike English, German language tends to not view rules are meant to be broken).

Comment: @CGCampbell Strictly speaking, it’s a _phonetic_ rule, not a grammatical rule. Grammar has nothing to do with pronunciation

Comment: @Silly but True, Re "*German language tends to not view rules are meant to be broken*", The point was that they're not from a German-speaking country, so anglicization is a very real possibility.

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn I would call it more a spelling rule, as the word first existed spoken and then was written down.

Comment: @SillybutTrue "When 'E and I go walking, the first is silent; the second does the talking"

Comment: Thanks.  I have wondered about this for over 40 years.

Answer (score 5):

Such a surname comes from German language where “ei” is being pronounced like the English “i” (as in “ride”). Therefore the right pronouncing would be LYE-ber (not actually LIE-ber, cause it has soft L)

Comment: Ah, but many people with German names in English-speaking countries have adopted anglicized pronunciations (or at least given up correcting people.  Do you have any evidence that _Fritz Leiber_ pronounced his name this way?

Comment: How it's pronounced in German is common knowledge. The question is about how the American writer Fritz Leiber pronounced his name.

Comment: @DavidW And it's not just English-speaking people who do this. For instance the French politician Nicolas Sarkozy does not pronounce his Hungarian surname as it woud be pronounced in Hungary. I'm not sure but I don't believe the German mathematician Dirichlet pronounced his name in exactly the French manner.

Comment: @user14111 Oh, absolutely.  My *Hungarian-first-language* relatives refer to their friends (Nagy) as "nah-GEE" because they've been trained over decades that's how they have to pronounce it to be understood.  And I've never met anyone in an English-speaking country who goes by, for example, "Veber." (German pronunciation of "w.")

Comment: @DavidW The name Nagy could be anglicized to Nodge or Nudge, which I think is about as close as you can get with English phonology, but I don't think that is common.

Comment: If Harvey Weinstein pronounces his surname like *wine-steen* then anything is possible

Comment: @Henry - Indeed. At best this answer shows that some German people with similar surnames sometimes pronounce their surnames a certain way.

Comment: Re: "LYE-ber (not actually LIE-ber, cause it has soft L)": I'm not sure what distinction you have in mind here, but *lie* and *lye* are pronounced identically in English (at least in the major dialects).

Comment: I'm with @ruakh - what on earth is a "soft L" [or a hard L for that matter] ? [Native Brit here]

Answer (score 5):

Greetings from Fullerton, California! As a fan and friend of Fritz Leiber, Jr. back in the 1970's and beyond, I had the opportunity to ask him (by letter) several questions about his and his characters' names. He confirmed that it is **Li/ber ("li as in like")**.

[Page three](https://www.flickr.com/photos/cthulhuwho1/4864863926/in/album-72157624536159977/) of [my fanzine](https://www.flickr.com/photos/cthulhuwho1/albums/72157624536159977/with/4864864214/) contains the relevant quotes.

> [image]
> <sub><sup>Q. ... Li/ber (li as in like). F.L. Correct!</sup></sub>
>
> <sub><sup>[Eldritch Leanings - Issue #5, 2 February, 1977](https://www.flickr.com/photos/cthulhuwho1/albums/72157624536159977/with/4864864214/)</sup></sub>

PS. Anyone interested in Fritz Leiber, Jr., might also enjoy [this section of my Blog](https://www.flickr.com/photos/cthulhuwho1/sets/72157625066410282/) devoted to him; and, you might just spot me in a couple of the pictures with him too.  I can't believe I'm still around to post this about Fritz!

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  This is great evidence, but it would be better if you quoted the relevant passages and included them directly in this answer, instead of having them in images on another site.  (This is a great aid for accessibility, among other reasons.)

Comment: William, did u meet him through chess by any chance? I think it is just amazing that Coming Attractions anticipated masks that we used during the Covid epidemic.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of adding some a picture and quote of the relevant passage from your album and tidying up the wording. We want this evidence to last as long as possible and having it stored locally is far better than an answer that says "go here" only to find that "here" has gone...

Answer (score -1):

It seems, in the US, names with *ei* coming from German are pronounced /aɪ/ (Lye ber) but names with *ei* coming from Yiddish are pronounced /i/ (Lee ber).  According to user's answer, Fritz Leiber (of German ancestry) used the German-type pronunciation.

When I was young, the composer-conductor Leonard Bernstein had his name frequently pronounced both ways, depending on the background of the person pronouncing it.  There was some comic with a routine about Albert Einstein pronouncing the name in the Yiddish way for effect.

Comment: As noted above, how it's pronounced *in German* is common knowledge. The question is about how the American writer Fritz Leiber pronounced his name